# How to set the Dx property of DHTMLX Scheduler Timeline view using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scheduler, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

In C#, I use this code to set the *Dx* property of the Timeline view

```
var timeline = new TimelineView("timeline", "EmployeeId");
timeline.Dx = 174;
```

But how can I achieve that using jQuery? I want to set the Dx property of an **existing** scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the client-side timeline configs are stored in **scheduler.matrix** property.
You can access certain config in following way:

```
scheduler.matrix["viewName"]
```

for example:

```
scheduler.matrix["timeline"].dx = 174;
scheduler.updateView();//apply changes
```